# reading files using generic array ref

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, ref

I am working on a small program which has some save and open functionality for a bunch of variables.
the variables are of various types, int - string - double and also arrays

I would like to implement a function which can cope all different data types

Let's say I have following variables

```
int var_int_1 = 1;
double var_double_1 = 2.2;
string  var_string_1 = "three";
int[] arr_int_1 = new int[5];
```

the saved file looks like this

```
var_int_1: 1
var_double_1: 2.2
var_string_1: "three"
arr_int_1:
   arr_int_1_00: 1;
   arr_int_1_01: 2;
```

my open-function will look like this

```
public bool open(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        string line;
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                extract_value_from_stream("var_int_1", line, ref var_int_1);
                extract_value_from_stream("var_double_1", line, ref var_double_1);
                extract_value_from_stream("var_string_1", line, ref var_string_1);
                extract_value_from_stream("arr_int_1", line, ref arr_int_1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch ...
```

the extract_value_from_stream function:

```
public void extract_array_from_stream<T>(string str_name, string line, ref T var_name)
    {
            if (typeof(T).IsArray) //T is an array => return array element
            {
                string index;
                str_name += "_";     //add "_" to name

                index = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(str_name) + str_name.Length,2);     //read index - 2 positions after str_name

                var_name[int.Parse(index)] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(line, typeof(T));
            }
            else  //if no array => return single value
            {
                str_name += ": ";                  //add ":" to name (see file)
                if (line.Contains(str_name))       //if line contains name
                {
                    line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(str_name) + str_name.Length);    //data = substring after str_name
                    var_name = (T)Convert.ChangeType(line, typeof(T));                  //cast line to correct type var_name
                }          
            }
        }
```

The no-array part works nicely. On the array part generates this error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `T`

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Can't you simply create a class that would have properties for all your variables and just serialize it to JSON using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) ?

Answer (score 0):

> save and open functionality for a bunch of variables

You want to use *serialization*. There are a few packages available to do that: binary, xml, json and other serialisers. Json may probably be the easiest option - it will deal with the most data types out of the box.

A quick example [from here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/14/writing-json-to-a-file-using-json-net)

```
Person person = GetPerson(); 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\person.json", json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The propper solution to your error message would be.. to add a constraint to your *generic* method call. You'll end up using the `System.Collections` namespace. Not the usual `System.Collections.Generic`, but you're able to keep it.. try implementing like this..

```
// note that you can add any base layer logic to a generic instance like this ...
public void ExtractArrayFromStream<T>(string x, string y, ref T array) where T : IList {
    // logical magic will be done here..
}
```

For more information about using contraints visit the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d5x73970.aspx).

---

***edit***...

This will skip the part to check whether it's an array or not.

Answer (score 0):

thank you both for the answers.

I decided to create an overload function

```
public void extract_value_from_stream<T>(string str_name, string line, ref T var_name)
```

and

```
public void extract_value_from_stream<T>(string str_name, string line, ref T[] var_name)
```